# How to add list element as key to the dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list as follows:

```
list1 = [((1, 4, 2),(0, 5, 8), (3, 6, 7)), ((1, 5, 2),(0, 4, 8), (3, 6, 7))]
```

I want my dictionary to have each element of list as key and a tuple value as follows:

```
dict[((1, 4, 2),(0, 5, 8), (3, 6, 7))] = (1,'None')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `{key: (1, None) for key in list1}`. (probably no quotes around `None`...)

Comment: and if i want to do this just for the 0th element?

Comment: `{list1[0]: (1, None) }`? are you sure this is the best way to represent your data?

Comment: what if I used: d = {list[0]:(0,"None")} , now I want to add second element the same way. How can i do that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries please take a tutorial first or try to google your question before posting it here... this is very basic stuff!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC I think you need:

```
d = {l:(1,'None') for l in list1}
d
{((1, 4, 2), (0, 5, 8), (3, 6, 7)): (1, 'None'),
 ((1, 5, 2), (0, 4, 8), (3, 6, 7)): (1, 'None')}
```

For 0th element:

```
d = {l:(1,'None') for l in list_val[0]}
d
{(1, 4, 2): (1, 'None'), (0, 5, 8): (1, 'None'), (3, 6, 7): (1, 'None')}
```

or

```
d = {v2:(1,'None')  for v1 in list1 for v2 in v1}
d
{(1, 4, 2): (1, 'None'),
 (0, 5, 8): (1, 'None'),
 (3, 6, 7): (1, 'None'),
 (1, 5, 2): (1, 'None'),
 (0, 4, 8): (1, 'None')}
```

Comment: Is it logical to have a nested tuple as a key in dictionary?

Comment: @SumedhJunghare That depends on user requirement. But dictionaries support tuples as keys.

Comment: what if I used: d = {list[0]:(0,"None")} , now I want to add second element the same way. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works fine. you just create a dictionary and assign key value pairs. Thas it!!
Look at my conversation with python interpreter below. ( i am using ipython! )

```
In [3]: d=dict()

In [4]: d['d']='4'

In [5]: d
Out[5]: {'d': '4'}

In [6]: d[(1,2,3)]=90

In [7]: d

Out[7]: {'d': '4', (1, 2, 3): 90}


In [9]: d[((1, 4, 2),(0, 5, 8), (3, 6, 7))] = (1,'None')

In [10]: d
Out[10]: {'d': '4', (1, 2, 3): 90, ((1, 4, 2), (0, 5, 8), (3, 6, 7)): (1, 'None')}
```